# Excel Countifs shows error or returns 0 when multiple criteria is set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the name of people if two of the criteria are matched, however, my code would either return "0" or will come with "#VALUE" error.
I am trying the match how "Ron" with "Section 1" in a given range.

My Code is:

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:F4,"*"&A7, B1:B4,A6)
```

Below is my table, I didn't know how else to upload the table here.
[Excel Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqUG2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in `B7:B9`:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$11,$C$6:$C$9,"?. "&$A12)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$11,$D$6:$D$9,"?. "&$A12)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$11,$E$6:$E$9,"?. "&$A12)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$11,$F$6:$F$9,"?. "&$A12)
```

and this formula in `B12:B14`:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$16,$C$6:$C$9,"?. "&$A17)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$16,$D$6:$D$9,"?. "&$A17)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$16,$E$6:$E$9,"?. "&$A17)
+COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$9,$A$16,$F$6:$F$9,"?. "&$A17)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to aggregate data when it has multiple columns like that. If you flatten it down into you can use a pivot table instead. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get "#VALUE" when using the ranges `C1:F4` and `B1:B4` because the ranges are not the same size. See "usage notes" here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function

You get a zero if you change `B1:B4` to `B1:F4` because as soon as excel encounters a cell that doesn't meet the criteria it returns a zero.

Based on the sample given, you can achieve the result you want using named ranges (e.g. -"Section1" is `B2:ZZ2`, "Section2" is `B3:ZZ3`, etc.) and then simply using `=COUNTIFS(Section1,"*"&A8)`

This won't work if the section numbers repeat on rows though without some manual manipulation: `=AND(COUNTIFS(Section1,"*"&A8),COUNTIFS(Section1.2,"*"&A8)`